# sublime.packages_path() broken in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am developing a plugin for sublime text 2 and am now switchting to sublime text 3. It seems to me that the command `sublime.packages_path()` - which worked fine in sublime text 2 - is broken in sublime text 3.

When executing the following line

```
print('sublime.packages_path() = ' + sublime.packages_path())
```

in sublime text 2 I get:

```
sublime.packages_path() = C:\Users\Mathias\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages
```

whereas sublime text 3 (exact same code) gives me:

```
sublime.packages_path() =
```

Does someone else have the same problem? When looking at the [plugin API](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html), it doesn't say that anything has changed. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you put `sublime.packages_path() ` in the console in st3?

Comment: In the console it gives me the full path as I would like it to have. That's really strange ... maybe sublime 3 is putting the compiled plugin code somewhere else than from where the console code is executed? It doesn't make sense to me ...